# Tailwind CSS Scrollbar only appearing on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I don't understand why my scrollbar is only appearing when I hover over it, otherwise it doesn't show meaning if you didn't know it was there it could be very difficult to navigate. The code where I'm using the scrollbar is shown below.

```
import FormInputField from "./FormInputField";
import { useState } from "react";
import FormDropdown from "./FormDropdown";

const CoreDetailsForm = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [dateOfBirth, setDateOfBirth] = useState('');
  const [height, setHeight] = useState('');
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState('');
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('');
  const [wingspan, setWingspan] = useState('');



  return (
    <div className="flex items-center p-2 flex-col h-4/5 w-3/6 rounded-xl bg-z12-gray opacity-70">
      <div className="text-3xl font-bold mt-8 tracking-wide">My Details</div>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-5 w-full mt-3 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar">
        <FormInputField title="First Name" name="first-name" type="text" changeHandler={setFirstName} />
        <FormInputField title="Surname" name="surname" type="text" changeHandler={setLastName} />
        <FormInputField title="Date of Birth" name="dob" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" changeHandler={setDateOfBirth} />
        <FormDropdown />
        <FormInputField title="Height (cm)" name="height" type="number" min={0} max={999} changeHandler={setHeight} />
        <FormInputField title="Weight (kg)" name="weight" type="number" min={0} max={999} changeHandler={setWeight} />
        <FormInputField title="Wingspan (cm)" name="wingspan" type="number" min={0} max={999} changeHandler={setWingspan} />
        <FormInputField title="Weight (kg)" name="weight" type="number" min={0} max={999} changeHandler={setWeight} />
        <FormInputField title="Wingspan (cm)" name="wingspan" type="number" min={0} max={999} changeHandler={setWingspan} />
  
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CoreDetailsForm;
```

I'm  using React with TypeScript and Tailwind CSS. I've tried using overflow-auto as well.

Answer (score -1):

try adding

`.scrollbar { display: block; }`

to your css file